# Batch Print multiples PDF on Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, pdf, printing

Im using Windows 8.1 and have multiple PDF files that i want to print. At the moment the only way i know to print those PDF files is by opening the file with the default Windows 8 PDF reader and then use the print option. It is a slow procedure when i have tons of PDF files to print.

I remember that on windows XP/7 i had the option to select all the files i wanted to print, right click on the selection and then choose print.. but thats not an option on windows 8.

Does anybody know about an app or way to achieve this on windows 8?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's the same on Windows 7 (as covered by the question I've marked as a possible duplicate), the right-click -> Print only shows up if you select 15 or LESS PDFs.  If you pick more than 15 the option isn't offered.

Comment: The question you marked refers to win7. on windows 8 it doesn't matter if you select one or two files, it wont work.

Comment: I have fully updated Win8.1 and the solution at the duplicate question works correctly. I see you are using the built-in PDF viewer to do this in 8, but do you have Acrobat Reader installed on your computer or another PDF viewer?

Comment: At this point, because we can confirm in its default state Windows 8 does operate the same way, this question is a duplicate. However, if we can gather more information we may be able to determine why you are experiencing something different, and that may be a new question we can indeed answer.

Comment: I have only the built in PDF viewer installed. nothing else :/ selecting two files doesn't bring the option to print. I have a Windows 8.1 pro VM running on the same HOST (HyperV) and it works on that one, the only difference is that the VM have Adobe Reader XI installed.

Answer (score 3):

#### How do I batch print multiple PDF files?

You can use [PDF2Printer](http://www.win8pdf.com/pdf-to-printer.html).

> PDF2Printer is a small application for Windows 8 that offers a quick way to print your PDF documents. It lets you integrate Print command into the right-click context menu for PDF files, allowing you to quickly select the printer you want to use to print your PDF document. In addition, the installation package also contains batch PDF print utility, which lets you print multiple PDF documents in one go as well as send selected PDF files to Virtual Printer application. Details after the jump.
>
> By default, the application doesn’t add Print shell extension to the right-click context menu. After the installation, open PDF2Printer Configuration Manager and enable Shell Integration (add a Print menu for PDF file type) option. Here, you can also tweak some other settings. For instance, Target Printer section allows you to define the action of Print command and includes Show Print Dialogue to choose a printer, Hide Print Dialogue and use system default printer and Hide Print Dialogue and always use the following printer options. You can set page scaling to No scaling, Fit to page  and Shrink large page. Finally, there’s also a Smart Rotation option (No rotation and Rotate pages to fit an output medium). Don’t forget to hit Apply after configuring your changes though.
>
> Once you’ve enabled Shell Integration option, right click any PDF document and you will see the Print command in the context menu.
>
> To print multiple files at once, open PDF2Printer Batch Print console
> (the application will automatically add its shortcut on the desktop).
> Here, you need to click Add File(s) or Add Folder to add the PDF
> documents you want to print. Now, configure your settings under Target
> Printer, Page Scaling and Smart Rotation sections and click Print
> button.
>
> **Licensing**
>
> Freeware. Free for commercial and non-commercial use.

Source: [PDF2Printer: Add Print Option To PDF File Right-Click Context Menu In Windows 8](http://www.win8pdf.com/pdf-to-printer.html)

Comment: It looks like you already have it installed. Is it free? is this the only option you know? Thank you.

Comment: I don't have it installed. It is freeware. I don't know of any others.